# Automapper:Converting object to JSON

Tags: c#, json, automapper

In my scenario, i would like to map a json to a concrete type, and the other way around using automapper version 6 with .net core.

Based on this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108128/6602770 I managed to map the JSON to the desired type. However, i do not seem to be able to reverse map it back to its JSON format.

My code looks like this:

The mapping profile:

```
 CreateMap<JToken, SomeDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ObjectId, cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["objectId"]); })
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());
```

and the mapping:

```
var json = _mapper.Map<JToken>(someDto);
```

There is no error, but it returned null.
I have also tried to set the profile with JObject instead of JToken, same result.

I also tried to create a seperate mapping profile, instead of using the "ReverseMap"

```
 public class SomeDtoProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeDtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SomeDto, JObject>()
            .ForMember(dest=> dest["objectId"], cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(src => src.ObjectId); })
            .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());

    }
}
```

but this throws an error of: "Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type json"

I would really like the solution the be using the AutoMapper, is it all possible or am i missing something basic ?

Comment: Why use automapper at all for this? Why not just convert your JSON directly to `SomeDto`? If the serialization/deserialization gets complex, you can use custom converters.

Comment: why you don't use [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) to serialize or deserialization?

Comment: I am already using automapper for the 1st way (JSON to SomeDto), it involves many properties and custom resolvers. I would like to keep the mapping logic for the other way using the same concept. Can it be done ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `JObject.FromObject` static factory method within your Mapper profile.

```
public class SomeDtoProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeDtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SomeDto, JObject>()
            .ConvertUsing(JObject.FromObject);
    }
}

public class SomeDto    
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then if we run the following test

```
public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void ShouldReturnJson()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new SomeDtoProfile()));


        var jObject = Mapper.Map<JObject>(new SomeDto {Name = "Bob"});

        Assert.Equal("{\r\n  \"Name\": \"Bob\"\r\n}", jObject.ToString());
    }
}
```

All is Green!

Comment: This method is working, though, how can i specify the mapping properties names ? and custom resolvers for it ? say i would like to map the "Name" to "objectName" ?

Comment: You'd need to specify them using the `json.net` functionality, in this case changing the field name would mean adding the attribute `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "objectName")]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right way ! I managed to accomplish it with the "ConstructUsing" method as follows: `CreateMap<SomeDto, JObject>() .ConstructUsing(src => { return JObject.FromObject(new { objectId = src.ObjectId, //... rest of the mapping... }); }) .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());`