# Map JSON object to POCO

Tags: c#, json.net, automapper

I would like to know if it is possible to map from a json object to a poco object.

The json object I am trying to deserialize and map:

```
    {
    "customers": [{
            "customerid": "",
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "companyname": "",
            "email": "",
            "language": "",
            "culture": "",
            "addressline1": "",
            "addressline2": "",
            "city": "",
            "country": "",
            "phonenumber": "",
            "postalcode": "",
            "region": "",
            "state": "",
            "domain": "",
            "partnerid": "",
            "subscriptions": [{
                "id": "",
                "offerid": "",
                "offername": "",
                "friendlyname": "",
                "quantity": "",
                "parentsubscriptionid": "",
                "creationdate": "",
                "effectivestartdate": "",
                "commitmentenddate": "",
                "status": "",
                "autorenewenabled": "",
                "billingtype": "",
                "partnerbillingcycle": "",
                "partnerid": "",
                "orderid": "",
                "offerlink": "",
                "parentsubscriptionlink": ""
            }]
        },
        {
            "customerid": "",
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "companyname": "",
            "email": "",
            "language": "",
            "culture": "",
            "addressline1": "",
            "addressline2": "",
            "city": "",
            "country": "",
            "phonenumber": "",
            "postalcode": "",
            "region": "",
            "state": "",
            "domain": "",
            "partnerid": "",
            "subscriptions": [{
                "id": "",
                "offerid": "",
                "offername": "",
                "friendlyname": "",
                "quantity": "",
                "parentsubscriptionid": "",
                "creationdate": "",
                "effectivestartdate": "",
                "commitmentenddate": "",
                "status": "",
                "autorenewenabled": "",
                "billingtype": "",
                "partnerbillingcycle": "",
                "partnerid": "",
                "orderid": "",
                "offerlink": "",
                "parentsubscriptionlink": ""
            }]
        },
        {
            "customerid": "",
            "firstname": "",
            "lastname": "",
            "companyname": "",
            "email": "",
            "language": "",
            "culture": "",
            "addressline1": "",
            "addressline2": "",
            "city": "",
            "country": "",
            "phonenumber": "",
            "postalcode": "",
            "region": "",
            "state": "",
            "domain": "",
            "partnerid": "",
            "subscriptions": [{
                "id": "",
                "offerid": "",
                "offername": "",
                "friendlyname": "",
                "quantity": "",
                "parentsubscriptionid": "",
                "creationdate": "",
                "effectivestartdate": "",
                "commitmentenddate": "",
                "status": "",
                "autorenewenabled": "",
                "billingtype": "",
                "partnerbillingcycle": "",
                "partnerid": "",
                "orderid": "",
                "offerlink": "",
                "parentsubscriptionlink": ""
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

the DTO that I am trying to map to

```
public class CustomersDTO
{
    public List<CustomerDTO> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDTO
{
    public BE.Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public List<BE.Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }       
}
```

and the mapping I am using

```
CreateMap<JObject, CustomersDTO>()
       .ForMember("Customers", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["customers"]); })                                    
        ;

CreateMap<JObject, BE.Customer>()
   .ForMember("CustomerGUID", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["customerid"]); })
   .ForMember("FirstName", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["firstname"]); })
   .ForMember("Surname", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["lastname"]); })
   .ForMember("CompanyName", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["companyname"]); })
   .ForMember("Email", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["email"]); })
   .ForMember("PreferredLanguage", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["language"]); })
   .ForMember("PreferredCurrency", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["culture"]); })
   .ForMember("Address1", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["addressline1"]); })
   .ForMember("Address2", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["addressline2"]); })
   .ForMember("Address3", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["city"]); })
   .ForMember("Address4", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["state"]); })
   .ForMember("MobileNumber", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["phonenumber"]); })
   .ForMember("PostalCode", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["postalcode"]); })
   .ForMember("Region", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["region"]); })
   .ForMember("CSPDomain", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["domain"]); })             
   ;

CreateMap<JObject, BE.Subscription>()
   .ForMember("OfferId", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["offerid"]); })
   .ForMember("OfferId", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["offerid"]); })
   .ForMember("Quantity", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["quantity"]); })
   .ForMember("FriendlyName", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["friendlyname"]); })
   .ForMember("AssignedDate", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["creationdate"]); })
   .ForMember("Status", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["status"]); })
   .ForMember("OfferURI", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["offerlink"]); })
   ;

public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public MapperConfiguration Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {                
            cfg.AddProfile<CustomerProfile>();
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

the code I am trying to execute

```
var customersJsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var customers = Mapper.Map<CustomersDTO>(customersJsonObj);
```

When I execute the line above the CustomersDTO.Customers property has the correct number of customer objects from the json array but the nested CustomerDTO.Customer and CustomerDTO.Subscriptions properties are null.

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly I need these properties populated with the correct values from the json object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string

I recommend to install WebEssential extension then you can use Newtonsoft JSON or any other library to convert json string to poco object.

Comment: You deserialize your JSON into a C# class with Newtownsoft, or another framework. That has nothing to do with AutoMapper. You would use that when you take your model and convert it to your database object.

Comment: First thing your JSON is not valid, first validate and correct JSON.

Comment: I tried to deserialze your json.. It is not valid one

Comment: @BhubanShrestha I need to map to an existing poco object, specifically public BE.Customer Customer { get; set; }
 public List<BE.Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

Comment: I don't see any mapping for `jo["subscriptions"]`, you might need to add that.

Comment: I have seen another example of what I am trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107415/automapperconverting-json-to-list-of-objects, my issue is that I have an array of objects and in each object there is a child property which is an array itself.

Comment: Updated your JSON, now its valid :)

Comment: @Abhay Dixit thank you and sorry for the typo.

Comment: @NjabuloMpungose did you get answer? looking similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the C# class, created from your JSON. Using this, try mapping - (you can use http://json2csharp.com to Convert your JSON into c# code)

```
public class Subscription
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string offerid { get; set; }
    public string offername { get; set; }
    public string friendlyname { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string parentsubscriptionid { get; set; }
    public string creationdate { get; set; }
    public string effectivestartdate { get; set; }
    public string commitmentenddate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string autorenewenabled { get; set; }
    public string billingtype { get; set; }
    public string partnerbillingcycle { get; set; }
    public string partnerid { get; set; }
    public string orderid { get; set; }
    public string offerlink { get; set; }
    public string parentsubscriptionlink { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string customerid { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string companyname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string culture { get; set; }
    public string addressline1 { get; set; }
    public string addressline2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string phonenumber { get; set; }
    public string postalcode { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string partnerid { get; set; }
    public List<Subscription> subscriptions { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Customer> customers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Ahbay Dixit if I already have POCO objects that I want to map to instead of creating new classes, what do I do?

Comment: you can use JSON.net -  var obj=  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);

Comment: if the property names from the source json object are different from the destination poco object how would the deserialization know which properties to map to between source and destination?

Comment: In that case use [JsonProperty("actualPropertyname")] attribute.

Comment: The POCO that I am trying to map to is auto-generated.

Comment: Can you show, how you have created your CustomerProfile?

Comment: My classes are being generated from wcf proxy.

Comment: Add your mapping code in configure() and see if it works.

Comment: When I mapped one object from the json array to a BE.Customer type instance the mapping worked fine, the issue that I am having is that I have an array of json objects that I need to map to a list of POCO BE.Customer types.

Comment: I added the mapping code to the Configure method and I am still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very late but today I used in my POC

Data.json

```
{
"Id": 1,
"FirstName": "Pankaj",
"LastName": "Rawat",
"Address": {
"Street": "Old Post Office",
"City": "Lansdowne",
"State": "Uttrakhand"
}
}
```

EmployeeProfile.cs

```
public class EmployeeProfile : Profile
{
    public EmployeeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<JObject, EmployeeDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, o => o.MapFrom(j => j["Id"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, o => o.MapFrom(j => j["FirstName"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, o => o.MapFrom(j => j["LastName"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, o => o.MapFrom(j => string.Concat(j["Address"]["Street"].ToString(), " ", j["Address"]["City"].ToString(), " ", j["Address"]["State"].ToString())));
    }
}
```

AutoMapperConfiguration.cs

```
internal class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<EmployeeProfile>());
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        var result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<EmployeeDTO>(jObject);
    }
}
```