# AutoMapper for JSON keys with same name as Model Fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have this AutoMapperProfile:

```
public AutoMapperJSON()
    {
        CreateMap<JToken, ModelObject>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("name")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.unformatted_street, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("unformatted_street")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.city, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("city")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.state, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("state")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.postcode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("postcode")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.street, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("street")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.locality, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("locality")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("id")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.short_id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("short_id")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.formatted_street, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("formatted_street")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.created_at, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("created_at")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.updated_at, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("updated_at")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.updated_by, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("updated_by")))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.deleted_at, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("deleted_at")));
    }
```

Here is an example JSON:

```
{ "id":"sample1",
"name":"sample2",
"city":"sample3",
"state":"sample4",
...
"created_at":"sample5",
"updated_at":"sample6",
"updated_by":"sample7",
"deleted_at":"sample8"}
```

And I would like to map it automatically using the automapper.

It's working properly. But is there a way to simplify this because all those JSON Keys are just the same name as the field in the Model.

Comment: Just deserialize from `JToken`.

Comment: could you provide more context? I'm very new to c# let alone asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

For the name of properties are the same ,you could  try with

```
CreateMap<JToken, ModelObject>().ConvertUsing(x => x.ToObject<ModelObject>() ?? default!);
```

Or directly without AutoMapper:

```
ModelObject targetobject=jtoken.ToObject<ModelObject>()
```